# how to solve this convex-linear optimization problem with linear constraints

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Consider the following optimization problem with $A > 0$, $B > 0$, $b_i \geq 0$ and each $f_i(x_i)$ being convex functions. Is there any good algorithm for solving this problem?

$\min_{x,y} \sum_i f_i(x_i)y_i$

s.t.

$\sum_i x_i \leq A$,

$\sum_i b_iy_i \leq B$,

$x_i \geq 0$,

$0 \leq y_i \leq 1$.

Comment: Please be more clear about parameters and variables. Why is $b_i \geq 0$ among the constraints? Do you have more information about $f_i$? Nonnegative and decreasing?

Comment: Baron might be suitable for this problem.

Comment: @LinAlg Thanks for your reply. In the problem, $x_i$ and $y_i$ are decision variables, and $A$, $B$, $b_i$ are given positive real numbers. $f_i$ is convex and decreasing ( it might be negative when $x_i$ is large). The problem can be thought of as placing $x$ resources on different places, each place $i$ incurs a cost $f_i(x_i)$, and $y_i$ denotes whether we choose place $i$. The second constraints is that we have budget constraint when choosing places.

Comment: This is neither a convex optimization problem nor a linear program, and shouldn't be labeled as such.

Comment: I might consider an alternating optimization approach wherein the $y$ values are fixed, then you solve the resulting convex optimization problem on $x$; then fix $x$ and solve the resulting linear program for $y$; and repeat. As with most heuristics for non-convex problems this is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thanks. I know this is bi-convex optimization problem and generally a local mimimum can be reached by the method you mentioned. But I just wonder if some more efficient algorithm exists by exploiting the structure of the problem.

Comment: @wbchu I am not aware of any. But in the future let me suggest you should always include what you know or what you have tried in your questions on Math.SE.